# Jetpack Compose alternative to View system's 'animateLayoutChanges'

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-jetpack-compose

What is the Jetpack Compose alternative to View system's 'animateLayoutChanges'? 'animateLayoutChanges' was a really easy and powerful way to animate layout changes.
I am not able to find a similar alternative in Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use modifier `Modifier.animateContentSize()` to automatically  animate size change

Comment: Are you sure it will actually replace anymateLayoutChanges? Aren't the two completely different things? The latter can animate new content as it enters composition, but the former just animates size from one value to another, while still being restricted to Composables that are already in composition

Answer (score 3):

There's the `AnimatedContent()` Composable

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedcontent